# How to plot standard deviation in a two way y axis plot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-deviation, geom

My data looks like this:

```
dput(NDVI)
structure(list(date = structure(c(19091, 19091, 19092, 19092, 
19093, 19093, 19094, 19094, 19095, 19095, 19096, 19096, 19097, 
19097, 19098, 19098, 19099, 19099, 19100, 19100, 19101, 19101, 
19102, 19102, 19103, 19103, 19104, 19104, 19105, 19105, 19106, 
19106, 19107, 19107, 19109, 19109, 19110, 19110, 19111, 19111, 
19112, 19112, 19113, 19113, 19114, 19114), class = "Date"), target = c("grass", 
"tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", 
"tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", 
"tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", 
"tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", 
"tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", 
"tree", "grass", "tree", "grass", "tree"), cNDVI = c(0.500272817021574, 
0.696083797270416, 0.489691804085761, 0.692795403987576, 0.570071858811957, 
0.698997926130435, 0.510441047568798, 0.693961708101642, 0.497010486993716, 
0.677617144059372, 0.489045582825731, 0.672753166123319, 0.488193790481098, 
0.663609030602538, 0.488885606064579, 0.644550512172325, 0.49094954276713, 
0.625607907143415, 0.477036686933829, 0.606892335456545, 0.46818825238034, 
0.598763281698822, 0.464516342335005, 0.594977691269838, 0.463896574547792, 
0.611135472706338, 0.60754090771395, 0.657544930586677, 0.483871290250419, 
0.641341913760879, 0.455301838422566, 0.625854396853959, 0.461233936815514, 
0.620543555588439, 0.467959523995231, 0.615756464377253, 0.441352232545973, 
0.597588129996248, 0.443084476959249, 0.588500193948734, 0.447515720605795, 
0.569604003059877, 0.445609012507936, 0.562613166422831, 0.495220373276007, 
0.58718847627638), TempAmb_Avg = c(13.16, NA, 7.929, NA, 12.29, 
NA, 10.37, NA, 10.91, NA, 10.14, NA, 9.15, NA, 11.25, NA, 9.17, 
NA, 11.94, NA, 11.26, NA, 9.45, NA, 9.09, NA, NA, NA, 6.447, 
NA, 9.14, NA, 8.02, NA, 10.54, NA, 10.12, NA, 11.56, NA, 12.3, 
NA, 10.82, NA, 11.17, NA), sd_NDVI = c(0.00206275442936463, 0.00483529298045758, 
0.00143646028945461, 0.00547488157335041, 0.0107421213523848, 
NA, 0.0057345829257413, 0.00239673774468361, 0.0122234699109748, 
0.0041293261382514, 0.00159520722600412, 0.00400695247999584, 
0.0014958900631327, 0.00207345410768067, 0.00142529228044798, 
0.00188141954676642, 0.00254072590985734, 0.00374571468034617, 
0.00162042982764391, 0.00371980695360771, 0.00149205232583476, 
0.00860693732895818, 0.00195420993834865, 0.0135370828066329, 
0.00267586232456702, 0.00366685362066545, 0.00548912106770043, 
0.0115656879529442, 0.00892427653015911, 0.00876020639322138, 
0.00793602431786174, 0.00308048721534673, 0.0022395875936781, 
0.00464228152203431, 0.010403456112334, 0.01197424728207, 0.0203370856390955, 
0.00842098123326728, 0.00179785152483323, 0.00238532744345886, 
0.00174703441109131, 0.0016114072840488, 0.00150060553756978, 
0.00245323735514388, 0.0276795273807586, 0.0187674033605546)), row.names = c(NA, 
46L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to plot the standard deviation **sd_NDVI**  on **cNDVI** in a two-way y-axis.

```
plot <- ggplot(NDVI)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg),stat="identity",colour="blue", fill="blue")+
  geom_point(aes(x=date, y=30*cNDVI,color=target),stat="identity")+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=30*cNDVI,color=target),stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=30*cNDVI-30*sd_NDVI, ymax=30*cNDVI+30*sd_NDVI, width=.2, position = position_dodge(0.05)),color=target, stat="identity")+
  labs(x="TIME",y="TºC") + theme_bw()
plot
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomErrorbar,  : 
  object 'target' not found
```

and despite the plot being displayed the standard deviation **sd_NDVI** in **cNDVI** is not.
How can I display the standard deviation in these conditions?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically here is your code with corrected synthax error. However I would like to attract your attention to the fact that there is almost no data for `tree` category and there is no obvious need to plot points and line for `30*sd_NDVI`. Probably it would be better to filter the dataset and remove unused geoms. You will also need to adjist legend as well.

You may adjust the desired output according to your needs.

```
NDVI %>% 
  mutate(target = as.factor(target)) %>% 
ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg, fill = target, color = target),
           stat="identity")+
  geom_point(aes(x=date, y=30*sd_NDVI, color=target),
             stat="identity")+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=30*sd_NDVI, color=target),
            stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = date, 
                    y = TempAmb_Avg,
                    ymin=TempAmb_Avg-30*sd_NDVI, 
                    ymax=TempAmb_Avg+30*sd_NDVI, 
                    width=.2,,
                    color = target
                    ),# position = position_dodge(0.05), 
                stat="identity") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(adjustcolor("blue", 0.5), adjustcolor("red", 0.5)), breaks = c("grass", "tree")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(adjustcolor("blue", 0.3), adjustcolor("red", 0.3)), breaks = c("grass", "tree"))+
  labs(x="TIME",y="TºC") + 
  theme_bw()
```

You will get somrthing like this:

[image]

**EDITED**

upon the edit of the question and comment:

```
NDVI %>% 
  mutate(target = as.factor(target)) %>% 
ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x=date, y=TempAmb_Avg, fill = target, color = target),
           stat="identity")+
  geom_point(aes(x=date, y=30*cNDVI , color=target), 
             #position = position_dodge(),
             stat="identity")+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=30*cNDVI, color=target), 
            #position = position_dodge(),
            stat="identity")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = date, 
                    y = cNDVI ,
                    ymin=30*cNDVI -30*sd_NDVI, 
                    ymax=30*cNDVI +30*sd_NDVI, 
                    width=.2,,
                    color = target
                    ), 
                #position = position_dodge(), 
                stat="identity") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(adjustcolor("blue", 0.5), adjustcolor("red", 0.5)), breaks = c("grass", "tree")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(adjustcolor("blue", 0.3), adjustcolor("red", 0.3)), breaks = c("grass", "tree"))+
  labs(x="TIME",y="TºC") + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. sorry I didn't mention in the question the geom_errorbar (standard deviation) is for the cNDVI column and not for the TempAmb_Avg. See the edits on the question.

Comment: @CláudioSiva Welcome. I have updated the answer as well. Errorbars are plotted.

Comment: the error bars are still on the TempAmb_Avg column data and they should be in the cNDVI data instead.

Comment: @CláudioSiva I have edited the answer upon your edit.

Comment: thank you once again. There are 2 things I'm trying to go around but I'm struggling. First I need to have a legend on the right side of the y-axis with the cNDVI range as well as it is with the "TºC" and second, the TempAmb_Avg should be independent of the target "grass" or "tree", in other words, the color and fill should be attributed independently.

Comment: @CláudioSiva This is above the range of the single question. I will be glad to help you should you ask new ones.